# How to Remove all tier prices from product and Add new tier prices in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, catalog, tierprice

Currently I have a custom API to live feed the product tier prices with data like this:

```
[
   {
    "sku":"X772A5",
    "customer_group_id":"1",
    "website_id":"2",
    "qty":"5",
    "price":"500"
   },
   {
    "sku":"X772A5",
    "customer_group_id":"2",
    "website_id":"2",
    "qty":"2",
    "price":"450"
   },
   {
    "sku":"X772A5",
    "customer_group_id":"1",
    "website_id":"1",
    "qty":"5",
    "price":"490"
   },
   {
    "sku":"X8911V",
    "customer_group_id":"2",
    "website_id":"1",
    "qty":"2",
    "price":"120"
   }
 ]
```

The data contains the product ski , customer group ID, website ID, product qty for the tier price, and product price. I want to remove all the product tier prices and then I can insert this new tier prices data, how can I achieve this?

```
public function execute(){
  $datas = $this->getInputDatas();
  $this->removeTierPrices($datas);//???
  foreach($datas as $data){
    $product = $this->getProductBySku($data['sku']); 
    $this->addTierPrice($product,$data);//??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For tier pricing, Magento Catalog module have their own **SaveHandler** and **UpdateHandler** files.

**File - vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/TierPrice/UpdateHandler.php**

**File - vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/TierPrice/SaveHandler.php**

Alternatively, you can truncate the table named `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` programmtically.

Make sure to check first on any local environment, it may break the pricing. Although, you can run the Magento pricing indexer after truncating the above table.

This is all depends what data being passed in the `$datas` parameter in `$this->removeTierPrices();`

```
\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface->setTierPrices($data);
```

One more way as code is already loading the `$product` object.

```
/**
     *  constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $datas = $this->getInputDatas();
        //$this->removeTierPrices($datas);//???
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
            //$product = $this->getProductBySku($data['sku']);
            try {
                $product = $this->productFactory->create();
                $product->load($product->getIdBySku($data['sku']));
                $product->setTierPrices($data);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->debug($data['sku'] . ' SKU not saved due to ' . $e->getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: so when we use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory::setTierPrices()`, it means we don't need to delete the tier prices before as it will override the tier prices automatically?

Comment: Yes you can give a try. It should work.

Comment: @jojo. is it work?